# Base URL connecting to database in Android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, database-connection

I am having a problem with android application connecting to my database.
Is the code I wrote correct? or do I need to setup a web hosting instead or running localhost server?

```
public static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/jobportal/api";
```

**Code:**

```
public interface Consts {
public static String JOB_PORTAL = "JobPortal";

public static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/jobportal/api";
public static String IS_REGISTER_SEEKER = "is_register_seeker";
public static String IS_REGISTER_RECRUITER = "is_register_recruiter";

/*API DETAILS*/
public static String POST_METHOD = "POST";
public static String SIGNUP_API_SEEKER = "register-new-seeker";
public static String SIGNUP_API_RECRUITER = "register-new-recruiter";
public static String LOGIN_API_SEEKER = "login-seeker";
public static String LOGIN_API_RECRUITER = "recruiter-login";
public static String ACTIVE_JOBS_API = "search-job";
public static String APPLY_JOB_API = "apply-on-job";
public static String POST_JOB_API = "post-job";
public static String GENERAL = "general ";
public static String FILL_SEEKER_PROFILE = "fill-seeker-profile";
public static String FILL_RECRUITER_PROFILE = "fill-recruiter-profile";
public static String SEEKER_CHANGE_PASSWORD = "seeker-change-password ";
public static String RECRUITER_CHANGE_PASSWORD = "recruiter-change-password ";
public static String FORGOT_PASSWORD = "forgot-password ";
public static String GET_RECRUITER_JOBS = "get-recruiter-jobs";
public static String JOB_APPLICATION = "job-application";
public static String DELETE_JOB = "delete-job";
public static String SEEKER_PROFILE_DETAIL_ON_JOB = "seeker-profile-detail-on-job";
public static String GET_RECRUITER_JOB_DETAIL = "get-recruiter-job-detail";
```

[Screenshot taken from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KafKw.png)

here is my database 
[image]

Comment: wht's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Add port in your url . for eg. `http://localhost:8080/jobportal/api ` if server runs in tomcat.

Comment: added but still won't work, I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't put variable inside interface class. Instead, you can just create a simple class like

```
public class Consts {
   public static final String JOB_PORTAL = "JobPortal";
   ....
   //etc
}
```

Second, i suggest you to use Retrofit to connect your mobile phone to database. Read the documentation [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **your URL is missing port# of database**. 
Check the URL with Port# and try connecting using it